# Is there a way to use external javascript/css in VS2012 bundling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, bundling-and-minification

It's pretty much in the title but to re-iterate: Is there a way to use Visual Studio's built in bundling to grab scripts from an external domain?

If not directly, would there be a way to include js/css files from an external domain within the sln so that bundling would work?

The question stems from the desire to have a domain which contains common javascript libs/snippets that can then be used by several other sites. All sites and files are owned and run by the same company.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can use a CDN http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Ah, I see I was missing the key word "cdn" in all of my searching. I can't seem to find any code examples that show how to combine several CDN files into one bundle. Is it the same as normal bundling? Also, after reading more (utilizing the cdn key word) I've found that it's not possible to bundle CDN and local files together. Is this still true or has someone figured it out yet?

Comment: The bundler will create separate links for each resource instead of packing them up had they been local to your mvc app. In your case I would consider packing your snippets into a *.min.js and serve it from your CDN.

Answer (score 0):

As Jasen said, a CDN is what you're describing. I know this is old but I found it on a search of the topic so I'm going to submit an example for those who also find it.

Here's a normal BundleConfig entry:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
                "~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"));
```

Here's the overload to ScriptBundle that allows using a CDN:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js").Include(
                "~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"));
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
bundles.UseCdn = true;
```

It's an overload of ScriptBundle, with the second string argument being the CDN URL. You also have to add the two flags following.